Barycenter of a triangle using the shoelace formula
Consider a triangle with vertices $\{V_i=[\xi_i\,\,\eta_i]'\}_{i=1}^3$. As is well known, the barycenter (or centroid) $g$ of a triangle coincides with the mean of its vertices, so that \begin{equation} g=\frac{V_1+V_2+V_3}{3} \end{equation} I am now convinced that this barycenter can also be computed in terms of the following shoelace formula: \begin{equation} \tilde{g}=\frac{A_1}{A_1+A_2+A_3}g_1+\frac{A_2}{A_1+A_2+A_3}g_2+\frac{A_3}{A_1+A_2+A_3}g_3 \end{equation} where, for $i=1,2,3$:

$g_i\triangleq(V_i+V_{i+1})/3$ is the barycenter of the triangle $\{[0\,\,0]',V_i, V_{i+1}\}$,
with the wrapping convention $V_4\triangleq V_1$;
$A_i\triangleq\text{det}[V_i\,\,V_{i+1}]/2$ is the area of the triangle
$\{[0\,\,0]',V_i, V_{i+1}\}$. More explicitly, still using the convention $\xi_{4}\triangleq \xi_1$, $\eta_4\triangleq \eta_1$,
\begin{equation}
   A_i=\frac{\text{det}[V_i\,\,V_{i+1}]}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\text{det}\left[\begin{array}{cc}
   \xi_i & \xi_{i+1} \\ \eta_i & \eta_{i+1}
   \end{array}\right]=\frac{\xi_i \eta_{i+1}-\eta_i\xi_{i+1}}{2}
   \end{equation}

I generated some random triplets of vertices and always found that $\tilde{g}=g$. I would now like to prove once and for all $\tilde{g}=g$, but I have some trouble.
My attempt
First, let $A\triangleq A_1+A_2+A_3$ and note that
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\tilde{g}&=\frac{A_1}{A}\left(g-\frac{V_3}{3}\right)+\frac{A_2}{A}\left(g-\frac{V_1}{3}\right)+\frac{A_3}{A}\left(g-\frac{V_2}{3}\right)\\
&=\underbrace{\left(\frac{A_1}{A}+\frac{A_2}{A}+\frac{A_3}{A}\right)}_{=1}g-\underbrace{\left(\frac{A_1}{3A}V_3+
\frac{A_2}{3A}V_1+\frac{A_3}{3A}V_2
\right)}_{\triangleq \Delta g}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Accordingly, the objective is to show that $\Delta g=[0\,\,0]'$. Assuming $A\neq 0$, this is equivalent to show that $A_1 V_3+A_2 V_1 + A_3 V_2 = [0\,\,0]'$. Now, if my computation are correct,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
A_1 V_3 = (\xi_1 \eta_2-\eta_1 \xi_2)\left[\begin{array}{c}
\xi_3 \\
\eta_3
\end{array}\right]\\
A_2 V_1 = (\xi_2 \eta_3-\eta_2 \xi_3)\left[\begin{array}{c}
\xi_1 \\
\eta_1
\end{array}\right]\\
A_3 V_2 = (\xi_3 \eta_1-\eta_3 \xi_1)\left[\begin{array}{c}
\xi_2 \\
\eta_2
\end{array}\right]\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Unfortunately, at this point by summing these three terms I don't see any simplification  that allows me to conclude that in general holds $A_1 V_3+A_2 V_1 + A_3 V_2 = [0\,\,0]'$.

Hint : Just expand them out and add!

Yes, you are right. By paying attention, one can see that the 6 terms in $A_1V_3+A_2V_1+A_3V_2$ can be split in 3 couples composed by terms that cancel with each other. Thank you.

Would you accept if I wrote this as an answer? Just to get it off the unanswered queue.

yes sure, go ahead.

As mentioned in the comments : Expanding and summing the three terms neatly cancels off the terms for both cooordinates, so everything checks out!
